# GridPane Ignoring TextField.setPrefColumnCount

Tags: javafx-8

I'm attempting to use TextField.setPrefColumnCount() to give me different sized text fields within a GridPane. The GridPane is sizing all of the fields to the longest field. Am I doing something wrong here, or do I need to explicitly set the maximum size of the fields to their preferred size for all the fields?

```
public class TestProject extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        BorderPane base = new BorderPane();
        GridPane inner = new GridPane();

        inner.setHgap(4);
        inner.setVgap(4);
        inner.setPadding(new Insets(8));
        inner.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        inner.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        inner.setStyle("-fx-border-color:red");

        Label lA = new Label("Label A");
        Label lB = new Label("Label B");
        Label lC = new Label("Label C");

        TextField tA = new TextField();
        tA.setPrefColumnCount(30);

        TextField tB = new TextField();
        tB.setPrefColumnCount(15);

        TextField tC = new TextField();
        tC.setPrefColumnCount(6);

        inner.addRow(0, lA, tA);
        inner.addRow(1, lB, tB);
        inner.addRow(2, lC, tC);

        base.setCenter(inner);
        base.setPrefWidth(800);
        base.setPrefHeight(600);

        Scene scene = new Scene(base);

        primaryStage.setTitle("GridPane TextField Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set GridPane's `fillWidth` property for child nodes like this:

```
GridPane.setFillWidth(tA, false);
GridPane.setFillWidth(tB, false);
GridPane.setFillWidth(tC, false);
```

Comment: Turns out the same setting on a ColumnConstraints will do it too. Thanks!